# Xtend in IntelliJ IDEA not generate file in src-gen

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dsl, xtend

I combine Xtext and Xtend. In project, where I write code for my DSL, Xtext work but XTend not generate file in src-gen (this is sources root on: `<project-root>/src-gen/`).
I have this code in function `doGenerate`

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        fsa.generateFile("a.txt",'a')
    }
```

Src-gen is always empty. In eclipse this work. How can I generate file in IntelliJ IDEA or how can I fix this problem. I run in gradle.

Comment: Did you try the following? Open the Gradle view (**View** | **Tool Windows** | **Gradle**), go to **Tasks** | **build** | **build** and run it by double clicking.

Comment: @GáborSzárnyas I try this too. How can I run new application from this build?

Comment: The **build** task should regenerate the sources. Some ideas: 1. If you have a class with a `main` method, simply go to the class and click **Run 'ClassName.main()'**. You may also create and run some JUnit tests. 2. Can you try to run the build from the command line? (e.g. `./gradlew build` or `gradle build`) and see what happens?

Comment: @GáborSzárnyas Still the same

Comment: Is your project originally an Eclipse plug-in? There are quite a few differences between the conventions of Eclipse and Gradle projects: in Eclipse, your main Java source files should be in the `src` dir, while in Gradle, your packages should be in `src/main/java`. Also, generated Xtext files may go to `src-gen` and `src/main/xtext-gen`, respectively. To manage these differences, you can specify custom layouts - see this [example](https://github.com/TypeFox/xtext-vscode/blob/master/gradle/source-layout.gradle) from TypeFox, the company behind Xtext.

Comment: @GáborSzárnyas This I use in Xtend project. This is ok. But in new project with `somefile.mydsl` not work any of this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run gradle task `runIdea`. I create Java project without any SDK.
When project is created, I add `"file.mydsl"` in `src` folder. Then I need change facet settings. I open project structure dialog (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S`), in the left-hand panel, click Facets, choose + icon and add DSL facet. Then apply and code is work. In src-gen create a file `"a.txt"`.